# would like to learn ajax can anyone tell me best pdf or online link for knowledge

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

hey freinds i am a new developer of ASP.NET in this world so i got little knowledge of ajax and would like to have more knowledge about that so please refer me the simplest and best knowledge source as i am new so that it should be easy for me to understand.............

thanks and regards

Comment: Personally I learned AJAX using one of Scott Allens' Pluralsight courses and using the book ASP MVC 4 in Action (chapter 6 I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best resources on the internet for web development is the w3school site.
**It combines tutorials and references of many component's API of web technologies**.

Take a tour at :

- http://www.w3schools.com/
- http://www.w3schools.com/js // for javascript
- http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP // for AJAX

Because of AJAX is more a method or technique based on JavaScript than an entire technology or programming language, you will not find any reference for AJAX, but you will find lots of tutorials and examples on the internet.

[AJAX W3School Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) can be a good start.

> AJAX is based on javascript, and ASP, .NET or C# can use it as it.
>   There is no Ajax for ASP (although it may be some quirks on IE*
>   interpretation of javascript).